# how to resolve xpath for selenium throws org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How to resolve Method threw `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException` exception when we have the xpath has `//td/text()[following-sibling::br and contains(.,'text')]`

Edited:
My bad, misspelled.
I need to select text1 only to identify the object but when I use the above XPath then selenium throws the exception. 
If I use //td[text='text1'] this identifies full td element. Once I find text1 then i need to find checkbox inside the label.

labelText is unique and text1 or text2 is unique.

Dom object looks like below.

```html
<td>
<label>labelText<input></label>
"text1"
<br>
<label>labelText<input></label>
"text2"
<br>
</td>
```

Comment: paste DOM for that element to cross check xpath you are using.

Comment: What exactly your goal?

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath,

```
//label/text()[following-sbling::br and contains(.,'text')]
                         ^^^^^^
```

has a syntax error.  This XPath,

```
//label/text()[following-sibling::br and contains(.,'text')]
```

would be syntactically correct.  Whether or not it functions as desired depends on the markup and the requirements, neither of which you've included in your question.

Comment: In Chrome this xpath works fine but selenium is throwing org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException

Updated the html snippet

Comment: If you're calling `driver.findElement()` then you should be sure that your XPath is selecting *elements*, not *text nodes*.   After you get an element, you can call `.getText()` if it's text that you want.

Comment: inside the label I need to select the check box and its value is in text1 or text2 then its difficult identify one object. That s where I have provided that xpath and selenium is throwing exception.

Comment: Sorry, but we've already undergone a round of corrections, and you've still not clearly expressed your goal.  Moving on.  Good luck.

Comment: Within the premise OP have provided along with the code trials involving `//label/text()` this should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning the clear requirement and I have mentioned it clearly.